# XFDF pdf opening in same window in IE

Tags: django, pdf, django-models, django-views, xfdf

I'm working on a project that collects data from the project then displays it using xfdf to populate a .pdf file.  Now when I use Chrome or Firefox it opens in a new tab which is exactly what I want, but some of my clients will be using IE, which opens it in the same window and causes some confusion.  What area of the code should I be looking at in order to tackle and solve this problem?

I can show code examples, just let me know what I need to show.

Thanks,

Steve

Edit:  When I click 'Print Application' button, it asks me to save or open the file.  When they click open, it opens in the same tab, I want it to appear in a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the best way to accomplish this is to alter your template linking to the PDF.  For example:

```
<a href="/path/to/my.pdf" target="_blank">Clicky!</a>
```

This should work in all browsers.

Comment: thanks for the answer Jack, could you check my edit though, I should have explained a bit more clearly.